# Alternatives to nested if else statements - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have multiple if else and nested if else statements. wondering is there any better way to write this? Appreciate any pointers. current code (if.else) is in UDF taking the dataframe cols as input to do this conditional checking of column values (~5 columns are being checked in this if else blocks) and returns true or false.

EDIT:Any other pattern like populating the conditions being checked in data frame and then compare against dataframe whose columns are being checked in udf like Type,Flag2, flag3,flag, Fieldmdl etc ?

```
val retValue = 0
if (Type.startsWith("xyx "))
 {
   if (flag2 == 666) 
    { 
       
            if (flag3.toInt  <= 100) 
            {
                if (flag3  == 65) 
                {
                    retValue = 1
          
                }
                retValue = 0
            }
            else 
            {
               if ((flag3 == "200" && flag5 == "10") || (flag3 == "198" && flag5== "10") )
                  {
                     if ((Fieldmdl.Contains("fff")) || (Fieldmdl.Contains("ggg")) || (Fieldmdl.Contains("hhh")) || (Fieldmdl.Contains("ttt yyy")) 
                        ) 
                        {
                            retValue = 1                                    
                        }
                        else {
                            retValue = 0
                        }

                    }
                else 
                {
                   retValue = 1       
                }   
            }
        
      
    }

}

if (Type.startsWith("waq"))
{ 
       
        if (flag3.toInt < 123 ) 
        {
            retValue = 0
        }       
        if (flag3 == "ggg" && (Fieldmdl == "aaa" || Fieldmdl == "bcc"))
        {
            retValue = 0       
        }
                
           retValue = 1       
            
        }
 }

<If (type.startswith("dddd"?>
{
    check somethig and set the retvalue = 0 or 1
}
```

Comment: It seems you can just use `if (cond1) 1 else if (cond2) 2 else if ....` where each `else if` is in its own line.

Comment: can you please some input & expected output.. also attache code which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logic is really simple you should aim to use either the dsl or sql via the expr column function where possible.  Spark's in-built functionality can be significantly faster as udfs require conversion of parameters and return values and cannot be in-lined with whole stage code gen.

Spark wise you can continue to use ifs, but you can also use case / when and nest those (to a degree dependent on Spark version, anything over 64k code gen can throw).  These Spark native conditions also benefit from constant folding or optimiser re-writes.

Based on the updated code example I'd note three Scala points,

1. prefer matching as [Sash Sinha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6328256/sash-sinha) mentioned
2. you should follow [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%c3%ada-su%c3%a1rez)'s guidance on using if as an expression, don't manipulate state where a simple expression result will work.
3. use actual boolean types.

e.g. you could, with a bit of infra use matching

```scala
class StartsWith(startsWith: String) {
  def unapply(arg: String): Option[(String)] =
    if (arg.startsWith(startsWith))
      Some(arg)
    else
      None
}

class Contains(contains: String) {
  def unapply(arg: String): Option[String] =
    if (arg contains contains)
      Some(contains)
    else
      None
}

object IsInt {
  def unapply(arg: String): Option[Int] =
    Try(arg.toInt).fold(_ => None, r => Some(r))
}

val xyx = new StartsWith("xyx ")
val waq = new StartsWith("waq")
val dddd = new StartsWith("dddd")

val contains_fff = new Contains("fff")
val contains_ggg = new Contains("ggg")
val contains_hhh = new Contains("hhh")
val contains_ttt_yyy = new Contains("ttt_yyy")

def theUDF(Type: String, flag2: Int, flag3: String, flag5: String, Fieldmdl: String): Boolean = {

  val retValue =
    (Type, flag2, flag3, flag5, Fieldmdl) match {
      case (xyx(_), 666, "65", _, _) => true
      case (xyx(_), 666, IsInt(f3), _, _) if f3 <= 100 => false
      case (xyx(_), 666, "200" | "198", "10",
        contains_fff(_) | contains_ggg(_) | contains_hhh(_) | contains_ttt_yyy(_) ) => true
      case (xyx(_), 666, "200" | "198", "10", _) => false
      case (xyx(_), 666, _, _, _) => true

      case (waq(_), _, IsInt(f3), _, _) if f3 < 123 => false
      case (waq(_), _, "ggg", "aaa" | "bcc", _) => false
      case (waq(_), _, _, _, _) => true

      case (dddd(_), _, _, _, _) => true

      case _ => false
    }

  retValue
}

assert(!theUDF("xyx ", 666, "200", "10", ""))
assert(theUDF("xyx ", 666, "200", "10", "hhh"))
assert(!theUDF("waq", 666, "ggg", "aaa", "hhh"))
assert(!theUDF("waq", 666, "2", "aaa", "hhh"))
assert(theUDF("waq", 666, "2000", "aa", "hhh"))
assert(theUDF("dddd", 666, "200", "10", "hhh"))
```

the above StartsWith, Contains and IsInt infra isn't necessary but it keeps the intent cleaner.

That said, most of what you have as examples would closely fit [Quality](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/) dq style checks, you wouldn't get a clear if else but you could more easily organise and audit the paths taken as well as getting the Spark in-built optimisations.  If you really needed to "override" the result, or had multiple udfs, the [folder](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/getting_started/flavours/#qualityfolder-rulefolderrunner) approach would work well.

You could, per [sarveshseri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1151929/sarveshseri)'s point organise the various sub if's in [lambdas](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/advanced/userFunctions/) to re-use the various tests in combination (even if you didn't use the rest of Quality).

This really only makes sense if you plan on changing this if's rules often or indeed if you'd add other if tree udf's.

Comment: updated the question with sample If else statements,

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your nested `if-else` statements by using pattern matching in Scala:

```scala
def yourFunction(cols: YourColumnsType): Int = cols match {
  case _ if condition1 && condition2 && ... => 1
  case _ if anotherCondition => 0
  // More cases as needed
  case _ => 1 // Default case
}
```

Comment: In my case, there are nested if-else, so not sure whether this case pattern work ? like in the above example if condition1 & condition2 are matched. there will be another nested if to cover additional conditions before the final output is derived.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are working on rare use cases where you need micro optimisations (as method calls cause a slowdown of few nano-seconds), using descriptive methods is better that multiple nested if-else.

```scala
if (condition1) handleCondition1()
else handleNotCondition1()

def handleCondition1(): Unit = {}

def handleNotCondition1(): Unit = 
  if (condition2) handleConition2()
  else handleNotCondition2()

def handleCondition2(): Unit = {}

def handleNotCondition2(): Unit = {}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I understood correctly, are you suggesting that I should move the code inside the if statements to a method?

Comment: Yes, break the long if-else logic chain into bite sized case handlers. The descriptive method names also allow the reader to actually understnad the reason/intent behind the condition check.